# Ruby splat operator: Array(1..10).equal? [*Array(1..10)] => false?

Tags: arrays, ruby, splat

I was looking at:

`hash_1 = Hash[*[Array("a".."j"), Array(1..10)].transpose.flatten]`

So I thought, the return with or without the splat, "*", looks the same - so why

`hash_1 = Hash[[Array("a".."j"), Array(1..10)].transpose.flatten]` returns `{}`  ?

Hence when I tested 
`Array(1..10).equal? [*Array(1..10)]` => false

Thus

`Hash[Array(1..10)]` => {}

`Hash[*Array(1..10)]` => {1=>2, 3=>4, 5=>6, 7=>8, 9=>10}

Please help.

Comment: `Array(1..10) == [*Array(1..10)]` is `true` so it's not clear why `.equal?` would return something to the contrary.

Comment: Yes yes yes! I also don't understand this! `==` returns `true` but `.equal?` return `false`

Comment: It could be a bug in Ruby. `equal?` is supposed to be an alias for `==`. Keep in mind `.equal?` is hardly ever used. `==` is the normal method.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F

Comment: @tadman I believe you're mistaken: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F says "Unlike ==, the equal? method should never be overridden by subclasses as it is used to determine object identity (that is, a.equal?(b) if and only if a is the same object as b)".  By exploding the array within `[]`, a new `Array` object is created.  The two match with `==`, but not with `equal?`.

Comment: @pjs Ah, thanks for clarifying there. Ruby has `==`, `===`, `eql?` and `equal?` just to keep you on your toes.

Answer (score 1):

## Hash[]

[Hash[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) expects an even number of arguments (or one single hash-like argument) :

```
Hash['a','b']
# {"a"=>"b"}
```

but

```
Hash[['a','b']]
# {}
```

In the second example, there's only one argument : an array with two strings, which doesn't answer `to_hash`. Depending on the Ruby version, it will display a warning or raise an `ArgumentError`.

## Hash[] with splat

For your example :

```
Hash[*Array(1..10)]
```

is the same as :

```
Hash[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
# {1=>2, 3=>4, 5=>6, 7=>8, 9=>10}
```

It's an even number of arguments, so a Hash can be created out of every pair.

Note that with an odd number of arguments :

```
 Hash[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 # ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation for Ruby Hash's `[]` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) says you can provide 1) pairs of values which will be used as keys and values, 2) an array of key-value pairs in the form of subarrays, or 3) an object which is convertible to a hash. `Hash[*Array(1..10)]` with the splat matches the first case, and a quick experiment in `irb` will show:

```
irb(main):001:0> Hash.new([1,2])
=> {}
```

which produces a `Hash` with a default value of `[1,2]` but containing no elements.  That's what gets passed as the hashable object when you use `Hash[Array(1..10)]`, i.e., without the splat.

As of Ruby 2.4 you get the following warning:

```
irb(main):002:0> Hash[[1,2]]
(irb):2: warning: wrong element type Integer at 0 (expected array)
(irb):2: warning: ignoring wrong elements is deprecated, remove them explicitly
(irb):2: warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release
(irb):2: warning: wrong element type Integer at 1 (expected array)
(irb):2: warning: ignoring wrong elements is deprecated, remove them explicitly
(irb):2: warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release
```

Comment: You're using the `Hash` Kernel method, which isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, but [`Hash()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) and [`Hash[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) are different methods.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and patience)! But I don't understand

Comment: @EricDuminil You're correct, I had meant to use `.new`.  Switching between too many languages these days...  I've cleaned it up now, I believe.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @ayuspark I made a mistake which I believe I've now cleaned up, see if the revised answer is more understandable.

Comment: Sorry!! First time asking questions here, didn't finish my comment. Ugh....Thank you for the answer (and patience)! But I don't understand `a_1 = Array(1..10)  #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, and `a_2 = *Array(1..10) ` also returns `#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. I did learn that splat operator can explode an array, so I understand your logic in our answer. But I don't understand the a_1 and a_2 returns.

Comment: In `irb`, see what happens when you type `a = 1,2,3`.  Ruby realizes that with multiple elements on the right-hand side, and a single element on the left, `a` must be an array.  The `a1` in your comment is an explicit array, so that's obvious, but with your `a2` expression you're exploding the list and then Ruby is assigning the results to an array again.

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem with your code, or rather with your exploratory test, that wasn't mentioned in the other answers so far:

[`BasicObject#equal?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F) is true IF AND ONLY IF the argument is *the same object* as the receiver. Not "an object with the same value", not "an object with the same representation", only if it is *the exact same object*. In other words, for `equal?` to be true, there is only *one single object* involved which is *both* the receiver *and* the argument. In your case, there are *two* objects (even though they have the same value and the same representation), so `equal?` can *never ever* return true.

You should not use `equal?`. It is one of the basic tenets of object-oriented programming that objects can simulate other objects (in fact, OO was *invented* in a language for simulations), but `equal?` allows you to distinguish between the real object and its simulation, and thus it breaks OO. I repeat: testing for reference equality makes your code non-OO. Frankly, it shouldn't even be possible in a "true" OO language, and it makes me sad that Ruby has it (although Java is worse, in Java it is even the *default* equality behavior).

You should (almost) always use [`==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D), which is semantic value equality. In some rare cases, you can use [`eql?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) (strict value equality). In the Ruby core libraries and standard libraries itself, `eql?` is only used together with [`hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-hash) for hash- and set-like behavior. (In fact, the only three places I can think of, where `eql?` is used in Ruby, is [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html), [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) (and [`SortedSet`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/SortedSet.html)), and the set-like array operations ([`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq), [`Array#uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21), [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-26), [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-7C), and [`Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2D)).) Never use `equal?`.

Note: [`===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is a different beast altogether and has nothing to do with equality. (It is kind of an unfortunate name to use three equals signs for something that is not equality.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I'm learning Ruby by myself, and it's always helpful to read well explained answers like yours.